# Triangle shape of anchor tag

Tags: css, css-shapes

I'm doing "interactive" menu with pure css , code :

```
<div class="holder">
   <ul>
       <li><a href="">one</a></li>
       <li><a href="">two</a></li>
       <li><a href="">three</a></li>
        <li><a href="">four</a></li>
       <li><a href="">five</a></li>
       <li><a href="">six</a></li>
       <li><a href="">seven</a></li>
       <li><a href="">eight</a></li>
   </ul> 

</div> 


*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.holder{
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    overflow:hidden;
    left:6em;
    width:26em;
    height:26em;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:1px solid black;

}
.holder ul li{
position:absolute;
width:10em;
height:10em;
    left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
transform-origin: 100% 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
border:1px solid black;
 margin-left:-10em;
    margin-top:-10em;
}
.holder ul li:nth-child(1){

    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) skew(45deg)
}
.holder ul li:nth-child(2){

    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg) skew(45deg)
}
.holder ul li:nth-child(3){

    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg) skew(45deg)
}
.holder ul li:nth-child(4){

    -webkit-transform:rotate(135deg) skew(45deg)
}
.holder ul li:nth-child(5){

    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg) skew(45deg)
}
.holder ul li:nth-child(6){

    -webkit-transform:rotate(225deg) skew(45deg)
}
.holder ul li:nth-child(7){

    -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg) skew(45deg)
}
.holder ul li:nth-child(8){

    -webkit-transform:rotate(315deg) skew(45deg)
}
.holder ul li a{
 display:block;  
 position:absolute;

 -webkit-transform:skew(-45deg) rotate(-67.5deg);
    width:14em;
    height:14em;

border-radius: 50%;
    bottom: -6.25em;
      right: -6.25em;
  text-decoration: none;
    text-align:Center;
    background-color:red;
    font-size: 1.18em;
   padding-top: 2.8em;

}
```

live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Trolstover/n9bge484/8/

but it seems it isnt possible to fill that empty space next to anchor tag , to make it look like triangle (a.k.a slice of pizza)

Is there any way how to reach that goal?

Comment: CSS-only is cool, and if you are doing this just as an exercise for fun or for the challenge, go for it.  But, if you are looking for something to actually use in a production website, SVG might be a better technology for this, with fewer quirks and rendering bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you are trying to do is create a downward triangle with pure CSS you can use the following snippet:

```css
#triangle-down {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 50px solid transparent;
 border-right: 50px solid transparent;
 border-top: 100px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle-down"></div>
```

Additional CSS shapes can be found here: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

**Edit**: I may have misunderstood the original pizza-like question.  I assumed you meant a downward triangle.

Instead it seems you want to simply fill in the white area with color.  If that is correct you could do the following:

`.holder{background:red;}`

Answer (score 3):

Try increasing the dimensions of the `li` and remove the border radius.

```
width:13em;
height:13em;
margin-left:-13em;
margin-top:-13em;
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.holder {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 6em;
  width: 26em;
  height: 26em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.holder ul li {
  position: absolute;
  width: 13em;
  height: 13em;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: -13em;
  margin-top: -13em;
}
.holder ul li:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) skew(45deg)
}
.holder ul li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) skew(45deg)
}
.holder ul li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) skew(45deg)
}
.holder ul li:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg) skew(45deg)
}
.holder ul li:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) skew(45deg)
}
.holder ul li:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg) skew(45deg)
}
.holder ul li:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) skew(45deg)
}
.holder ul li:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg) skew(45deg)
}
.holder ul li a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg) rotate(-67.5deg);
  width: 14em;
  height: 14em;
  bottom: -6.25em;
  right: -6.25em;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: Center;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 1.18em;
  padding-top: 2.8em;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:alert('1')">one</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:alert('2')">two</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:alert('3')">three</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:alert('4')">four</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:alert('5')">five</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:alert('6')">six</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:alert('7')">seven</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:alert('8')">eight</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: it worked thanks , but there is another problem , http://jsfiddle.net/Trolstover/n9bge484/9/ as you can see when i remove border of li elements there is a small "uncollored" gap between last two of em

Comment: That looks like a chrome rendering issue, which was there in your previous fiddle.

Comment: If you rotate the holder, the rendering issue changes.  Play with [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n9bge484/11/), using the text box to change the rotation until you find one that works.

Comment: yes tried changing holder , altought it did helped to solve this  "render issue" , if i change background-color of anchor element via :hover , and its rotated without this rendering issue , the hover background-color is blurred = demo from your example   http://jsfiddle.net/Trolstover/n9bge484/12/